# Data sharing - SQLite vs Shared Memory IPC

Tags: sqlite, shared-memory, embedded-linux

I would like to get your opinion regarding a design implementation for data sharing.

I am working on Linux embedded device (mips 200 Mhz) and I want to have some sort of data sharing between multiple processes which can either read or write multiple parameters at once.

This data holds ~200 string parameters which are updated every second.
Process may access to data around ~10 times in 1 second.

I would very much like to try and make the design efficient (CPU / Mem).

This data is not required to be persistent and will be recreated every reboot.

Currently, I am considering two options:

1. Using shard memory IPC (SHM) + semaphore (locking on all SHM).
2. To use SQLite memory based DB.

For either option, I will supply a C interface library which will perform all the logic of DB operation.

For SHM, this mean locking/unlocking the semaphore and access the parameters which can be referred as an indexed array.

For SQLite, my library will be a wrapper for the SQLite interface library, so the process will not have to know SQL syntax, (some parsing should be done for queries and reply).

I believe that shared memory is more efficient:

No need to use and parse SQL, and it is accessed as an array.

Saying that, there are some pros as well for using SQLite:
Already working and debugged (DB level).
Add flexibility.
Used widely in many embedded systems.

Getting to the point,

Performance wise, I have no experience with SQLite, I would appreciate if you can share your opinions and experience.

Thanks

Comment: Well, what are the *requirements*? SHM (exposes "raw bits", direct) is entirely different from a DBMS (exposes "information", ACID, etc.) Also, SQLite *relies on file locks* and write-write/write-read contention is one of SQLite's "weak spots"; the behavior/semantics of when the locks are obtained is well-documened on the site.

Comment: There are other (faster, but not necessarily relational) DB systems - aka BDB style - that may a better fit, and are also well tested. They can have far less overhead than SQLite, which can make a difference on "very slow" (as in todays standards) systems.

Comment: (I would likely start with SHM or a [BDB-style DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB). The former will allow fine-grained/custom locking if needed, but is just a tad more work. I wouldn't worry about performance of the latter; performance numbers will tell you if you should [have], but getting it working is *far* more important at this stage.)

Comment: Generally, the requirements are to collect different parameters from the device (stored at different locations kernel/ other core/ files etc…)
This will be done with collecting process/es (writing the data)
Then to be able to expose the data in one central location and a single API.
The data should be accessed easily by processes such as web-UI etc...

Comment: For "easily processed", a DBD-style DB wins over SHM hands-down for writing and reading key-value pairs :) Now, SQLite (with it's SQL syntax, although it is possible to use SQLite over the official BDB these days, for a $$$, I believe) has the ultimate advantage *if doing relational queries*. If key-value pairs suffice in a [self managed] hierarchal model, then relational queries gain little.

Comment: Thanks pst, I will take a look on your idea of BDB style.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's in-memory databases cannot be shared between processes, but you could put the DB file into `tmpfs`.

However, SQLite does not do any synchronization between processes. It *does* lock the DB file to prevent update conflicts, but if one process finds the file already locked, it just waits for a random amount of time.

For *efficient* communication between processes, you need to use a mechanism like SHM/semaphores or pipes.

Comment: "SQLite does not do any synchronization between processes. It does lock the DB file to prevent update conflicts" This is a contradiction: A lock on a file that two processes access is a form of synchronization between those processes. Also I believe locking is at the table level "if one process finds the file already locked, it just waits for a random amount of time" This sounds highly unlikely, I think SQLite asks to be notified by the OS when the lock is release.

Comment: The locking [is done on the file level](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html), not on the process level; this means that even two connections in the same process will use file locking. See the [default busy handler](https://github.com/LuaDist/libsqlite/blob/master/src/main.c#L859): there is no unlock notification. Table locking is used only with shared-cache mode, i.e., when two connections in the same process agree to share their accesses to the same database.